# How to select * from table () referencing a function from dblink

Tags: oracle, select, plsql, user-defined-functions, dblink

I'm just starting with PL/SQL. I have a function (table valued), and I can select it running:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE(fn_getsomething());
```

Ok, but I have to select a similar function (table valued as well) from a remote database @dbfs. How can I write this sentence?

I tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE (fn_get_rps_to_rm@dbfs())
//or
SELECT *
FROM TABLE (fn_get_rps_to_rm()@dbfs());
```

And it returns : **00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"**

I had looked for similar questions, talking about table valued functions and dblink and I didn't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend creating a view on the remote node say:

```
create or replace view fn_getsomething_view as
SELECT *
FROM TABLE(fn_getsomething());
```

then query from that view with the link, for example:

```
select * from fn_getsomething_view@dbfs;
```

hope this helps.